# How to dynamically show the value in input field related with select option

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to get the value inside input field whenever an option is selected from select box. For now, whenever I select an option, the related values are showing but it is in select option format. I just want it in input field.

Here is my HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="organisation" id="mainpage">
    <option selected="">Select</option>
    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
        @if($u->created_by == $userId)
           <option value="{{ $u->id }}" id="{{ $u->id }}">{{ $u->name }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I just want that the below selection box will come in input field.

```
<select class="form-control" id="mainsection" required>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
        @if($u->created_by == $userId)
            <option value="{{ $u->user_id }}" data-parent="{{ $u->id }}">{{ $u->user_id }}</option>                             
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Here is my Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("select#mainpage").on('change',function () {     
        jQuery("select#mainsection").find('option').css('display', 'none');
        var idclassurl = jQuery("select#mainpage :selected").attr('id')
        jQuery("select#mainsection").find('option[data-parent="'+idclassurl+'"]').css('display', 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please show js errors from console tab

Comment: the above code is working perfect, no issues. I just want that the option showing in second select box will show in input field after selecting option from first select box,

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
<select class="form-control" id="mainsection" required>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
        @if($u->created_by == $userId)
            <option value="{{ $u->user_id }}" data-parent="{{ $u->id }}">{{ $u->user_id }}</option>                             
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```

with this code

```
<div class="form-control" id="mainsection">
    @foreach($users as $k=>$u)
        @if($u->created_by == $userId)
            <input id="{{ $u->user_id }}" data-parent="{{ $u->id }}" value="{{ $u->user_id }}">                             
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

and change your script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("select#mainpage").on('change',function () {     
        jQuery("#mainsection").find('input').css('display', 'none');
        var idclassurl = jQuery("select#mainpage :selected").attr('id')
        jQuery("#mainsection").find('input[data-parent="'+idclassurl+'"]').css('display', 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Above solution is according to your already developed code concept. There are few other easy methods too.

Comment: I have already tried this. In this there is a problem i.e. it will show all options,

Comment: try this in fiddle with same snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/vz5cn3wf/

Comment: ok, I tried but it stores the last value in database not the selected one

Comment: Please check the "Already tried this" part, this shows the same result as in your JS FIDDLE, and both are storing the last value in database